# Excel - Range within a range

Tags: excel, date, time, range

Hope you can help me. 
I have two columns (Start Time, End Time), like this:

[Excel columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sYBV.jpg)

And I want to see if there is a range (Column E) within the range of "Start time" and "End Time"

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are currently simply expecting us to solve the problem **for you**. **PLEASE** give it a try **on your own**, and if you have no clue please search online and learn the basics and then show us what you've achieved - and if you get stuck along the way, feel free to come back and ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all I have to say.. to achieve what you need, you'll really have to do :

1. a lot of tries using date() , hour(), minutes(), and other date/time related function.
2. just post what you had tried and didn't work.. It'll really helps others to search/drill down/scoping of the questions.

promise me you'll update (at least something) in your question post. If I were in your position.. it IS quite hard to find a direct solution of what you need. Specifically, it may need more than one formula/steps in order to achieve this goal. Ready? Let's start.

+-----[part1 of 3]-----+

Key point : 
- excel saves date as integers and time as floating point numbers. you can view this `=value(A2)` | It means, even though we view the cell as `12/07/2018 00:31` but the cell is processed as `43441.0215277778`arithmetically.

- hour(), day(), minutes() can extract the hour from the date formatted cell directly. since you only want to process the hours.. try to read more on hour() capabilities in excel help/online.
- there is a way to make excel answer YES or NO . it is IF() function. also and() and or() function. Have a read and play with it too. (:

+-----[part2 of 3]-----+

I always hold to the principle of : there is more than one way of doing things.. Suitability (for me)  job intent and case dependent. I cannot say my solution is the best since what works best for me may not make the same sense to others.

In this case however, (in order not to confuse readers) I'll recommend the use of hour() and if() function.

+-----[part3 of 3]-----+

Now.. start coding.. Let me know if you get stuck understanding the equations here. /(^_^)

In D1 to AB1 fill in these numbers :

```
D1   -->   0
E1   -->   1
F1   -->   2
G1   -->   3
H1   -->   4
I1   -->   5
J1   -->   6
K1   -->   7
L1   -->   8
M1   -->   9
N1   -->   10
O1   -->   11
P1   -->   12
Q1   -->   13
R1   -->   14
S1   -->   15
T1   -->   16
U1   -->   17
V1   -->   18
W1   -->   19
X1   -->   20
Y1   -->   21
Z1   -->   22
AA1   -->   23
AB1   -->   0
```

then,

```
D2   -->   =IF(AND(HOUR($A2)<=D$1,HOUR($B2)>=E$1),1,"")
```

drag it until AB5. then,

```
D6   -->   =SUM(D2:D5)
```

drag it until AB6. I think that's it.

Hope that helps. (:

Do drop in comment if you don't get what's happening.